# Store Angularjs form data in database using php

Tags: php, angularjs

My index.html:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-submit="save(user)">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/><br /><br />
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.email"/><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

script.js

```
   function Ctrl($scope,$http)
   {

$scope.save = function(user)
{
   var data={
   name: user.name,
   email:user.email
        }
        console.log(data);
 $http.post("insert.php",data).success(function(data){
   console.log(data);
 });


}
 }
```

insert.php

```
<? php

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
  // use $data instead of $_POST
   print_r($data);

  ?>
```

This is my code to store form data in database..
but its not working...i am complete new to angularjs...i donno where i went wrong...
pls help me..

Comment: `insert.php` - is this a valid url? Haven't used php in ages but I can't remember putting .php on the end of everything! Depends on your server config of course... You might put a .error() callback and see if that returns anything.

Comment: @IanHaggerty:its not giving anything

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors:

**JS** (You need to `$scope` to link your variables)

```
$scope.save = function() {
   var data = {
      name: $scope.user.name,
      email: $scope.user.email
   }

   $http.post("insert.php", data).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

   });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-submit="save()">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/><br /><br />
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.email"/><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: still the same thing happening...its not going to insert.php...in success function if i say console.log(data) it displaying the complete php code...i donno y...